# responseJson comparison always entering wrong if

Tags: javascript, react-native

When i try to compare `if (responseJson === "wrong")`, it always goes to the `else` even though i placed an alert, that tells me the value of responseJson is "wrong".
Here are the codes of the PHP file and the Form.js

```js
<?php
include("Config.php");

 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 
$username = $obj['username'];
$password = $obj['password'];

$link = mysqli_connect("$HostName", "$HostUser", "$HostPass", "$DatabaseName");
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$check = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT mail FROM Usuarios WHERE `mail`= '$username' AND `contrasena`= '$password'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($check);
    if ($numrows == 0 )
    {
     $InvalidMSG = "wrong";
     trim($InvalidMSG);
     $InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
     
     echo($InvalidMSGJSon);
    }
else {
     //login user
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
     $mail = $row['mail'];
     $array = array('mail' => $mail); 
     $answer = json_encode($array);//"Login Done," . $mail;
     echo($answer);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import styles from './From.styles.js'


export default class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
     UserEmail: '',
     UserPassword: ''
}
   

UserLoginFunction = () =>{
 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;
 const url = 'https://andrianodna.000webhostapp.com/Login.php'

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    username: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword
  })
})
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((responseJson) => {

      if(responseJson === "wrong")
        {
             //Alert.alert('E-Mail o Contraseña equivocados')
             Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }
        else{
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Router' , { Email:UserEmail});
          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style ={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'E-Mail'
            onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'/>

            <TextInput style ={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Contraseña'
            onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            secureTextEntry = {true} />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.UserLoginFunction} style={styles.Button}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button2}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type2}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      );
  }
}
```

The userEmail and userPassword give me the values i want, i just want to not go to the Router.js when the states said earlier, are wrong. I tried with \n and \r on different combinations. Also with " == " instead of " === ".

Comment: Try to test with "==" only. When you use "===", you're testing the type too, and not just the value.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The value you are receiving from server (`"wrong"`) has `\r\n` at the beginning, that's why the condition is failing. I tried with `responseJson === '\r\n"wrong"'` (quite wired) and condition was `true`. Please note that `"` is also part of the returned string.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Oooh that must be it! I tried those but in the single quote instead of double, I'll try that soon. Thanks!

Comment: still doesn't work >.< thanks anyway. I'll keep trying